# How to updatte data to database through service or alarm manager

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am newbie in android development. I have a requirement where i should check the user location and then i have a list of all the locations in database. Now in my app I need to calculate the distance from current location with the list of location stored in database and to show the distance in ListView.

Now i am stuck with the point that how should i proceed.

Now My approach what i thought is like:

- I should write a service which should load data from db
- I should calculate the distance in the from current location to the list of location in db
- Then i should populate the distance into the db.
- Then i should schedule it.

Is it the correct approach or there is something better. I read many post and blogs but i am confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform db operation in background using handler to get and populate data. For more checkout this link for running services...I hope this will help you out.

http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/11/running-service-in-background-on.html